# Run a minecraft server at boot

Tags: raspbian, boot, server, minecraft

I have a Raspberry Pi model 2. I have a `start.sh` file in my MinecraftServer folder in the directory  `/home/pi/MinecraftServer`  it starts the Java server which is required to play Minecraft. I want this to run at boot. I have tried using the  `crontab -e`  command and placed this in it  `@reboot sh /home/pi/MinecraftServer/start.sh`  doesn't work.

I tried to put it in  `rc.local`  but that does not do the trick. Any suggestions? I even tried running it with  `screen`  in the  `/etc/init.d`  directory, but that doens't work either. I can start it manually, but I want it to start at boot.

Comment: If you put it in `rc.local`, you probably have to use `&` at the end to fork it, unless it does that already.  You could also try `/path/to/start.sh &> /tmp/start.sh.log &` (the `&>` redirects output) to see if this provides any clues about why it isn't working.

Comment: Will try it now!

Comment: @goldilocks ain't getting any output. I did the & but forgot to write it down.

Comment: Is `start.sh` that long?  Paste it in.

Comment: <code>java -Xmx1024M -Xms512M -jar minecraft_server.1.8.1.jar nogui</code> this is all the code there is, it starts the minecraft server. Both scripts are in the same directory

Comment: Try adding `echo "Starting server" > /tmp/mcserver.log` at the top, then use `&>>` inside the script, like `java -Xmx1024M -Xms512M -jar minecraft_server.1.8.1.jar nogui &>> /tmp/mcserver.log`.  The extra `>` in `&>>` appends instead of overwrites.  This way there for sure should be a `/tmp/mcserver.log` with at least one line in it (to check if this is actually happening) ...and hopefully more.

Comment: @goldilocks will try it now!

Comment: @goldilocks The only thing in mcserver.log is "Starting server", nothing more.

Comment: Kind of unfortunate minecraft doesn't provide any debugging output.  Unless it has a log of it's own somewhere (have you checked that)?  It may also/instead log via syslog, try `grep -i minecraft /var/log/syslog` (if you are using raspbian jessie you'll have to use systemd's journal instead).

Comment: @goldilocks I have a new thing, if I try to run it outside of the MinecraftServer directory I get the error ` Error: Unable to access jarfile minecraft_server.1.8.1.jar `

Comment: Try `cd /path/to/minecraft/directory` at the top of the script, that way it will always run from there.

Comment: @goldilocks Sir, you have solved the problem. Thank you so much! I'll explain it, because the script I used was for starting the server in the same directory it did not work. But as you just said, placing <code> cd /path/to/minecraft/directory </code> on top of the script solved the problem. I just put the path to the script in the rc.local and that was it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be an evironment issue.

```
java -Xmx1024M -Xms512M -jar minecraft_server.1.8.1.jar nogui
```

That isn't telling it where minecraft_server.1.8.1.jar is located so it needs to be executed from the same directory. I would try adding the full path to the jar file in your start.sh like this:

```
java -Xmx1024M -Xms512M -jar /home/pi/MinecraftServer/minecraft_server.1.8.1.jar nogui
```

or I would change your cron to run out of the same directory as start.sh like this:

```
@reboot sh cd /home/pi/MinecraftServer;./start.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

What you really want, probably, is to create a minecraft service in init.d . I found one at [gamepedia](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Server_startup_script) that I have modified slightly into this (still needs work, though):

```
#!/bin/bash
# /etc/init.d/minecraft
# version 0.3.9 2012-08-13 (YYYY-MM-DD)

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:   minecraft
# Required-Start: $local_fs $remote_fs
# Required-Stop:  $local_fs $remote_fs
# Should-Start:   $network
# Should-Stop:    $network
# Default-Start:  2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:   0 1 6
# Short-Description:    Minecraft server
# Description:    Starts the minecraft server
### END INIT INFO

#Settings
SERVICE='minecraft_server.jar'
OPTIONS='nogui'
USERNAME='minecraft'
WORLD='world'
MCPATH='/home/minecraft'
MCLOG='logs/latest.log'
BACKUPPATH='/home/minecraft/backup'
MAXHEAP=2048
MINHEAP=512
HISTORY=1024
CPU_COUNT=1
INVOCATION="java -Xmx${MAXHEAP}M -Xms${MINHEAP}M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC \
-XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing -XX:+AggressiveOpts -jar $SERVICE $OPTIONS"

ME=`whoami`
as_user() {
  #sudo -u minecraft $1
  if [ $ME == $USERNAME ] ; then
    bash -c "$1"
  else
    su -s /bin/bash $USERNAME -c "$1"
  fi
}

mc_start() {
  if  pgrep -u $USERNAME -f $SERVICE > /dev/null
  then
    echo "$SERVICE is already running!"
  else
    echo "Starting $SERVICE..."
    cd $MCPATH
    echo "In $MCPATH"
    as_user "screen -h $HISTORY -dmS minecraft $INVOCATION"
    sleep 7
    if pgrep -u $USERNAME -f $SERVICE > /dev/null
    then
      echo "$SERVICE is now running."
    else
      echo "Error! Could not start $SERVICE!"
    fi
  fi
}

mc_saveoff() {
  if pgrep -u $USERNAME -f $SERVICE > /dev/null
  then
    echo "$SERVICE is running... suspending saves"
    as_user "screen -p 0 -S minecraft -X eval 'stuff \"say SERVER BACKUP STARTING. Server going readonly...\"\015'"
    as_user "screen -p 0 -S minecraft -X eval 'stuff \"save-off\"\015'"
    as_user "screen -p 0 -S minecraft -X eval 'stuff \"save-all\"\015'"
    sync
    sleep 10
  else
    echo "$SERVICE is not running. Not suspending saves."
  fi
}

mc_saveon() {
  if pgrep -u $USERNAME -f $SERVICE > /dev/null
  then
    echo "$SERVICE is running... re-enabling saves"
    as_user "screen -p 0 -S minecraft -X eval 'stuff \"save-on\"\015'"
    as_user "screen -p 0 -S minecraft -X eval 'stuff \"say SERVER BACKUP ENDED. Server going read-write...\"\015'"
  else
    echo "$SERVICE is not running. Not resuming saves."
  fi
}

mc_stop() {
  if pgrep -u $USERNAME -f $SERVICE > /dev/null
  then
    echo "Stopping $SERVICE"
    as_user "screen -p 0 -S minecraft -X eval 'stuff \"say SERVER SHUTTING DOWN IN 10 SECONDS. Saving map...\"\015'"
    as_user "screen -p 0 -S minecraft -X eval 'stuff \"save-all\"\015'"
    sleep 10
    as_user "screen -p 0 -S minecraft -X eval 'stuff \"stop\"\015'"
    sleep 7
  else
    echo "$SERVICE was not running."
  fi
  if pgrep -u $USERNAME -f $SERVICE > /dev/null
  then
    echo "Error! $SERVICE could not be stopped."
  else
    echo "$SERVICE is stopped."
  fi
}

mc_update() {
  if pgrep -u $USERNAME -f $SERVICE > /dev/null
  then
    echo "$SERVICE is running! Will not start update."
  else
    MC_SERVER_URL=http://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftDownload/launcher/minecraft_server.jar?v=`date | sed "s/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/_/g"`
    as_user "cd $MCPATH && wget -q -O $MCPATH/minecraft_server.jar.update $MC_SERVER_URL"
    if [ -f $MCPATH/minecraft_server.jar.update ]
    then
      if `diff $MCPATH/$SERVICE $MCPATH/minecraft_server.jar.update >/dev/null`
      then 
        echo "You are already running the latest version of $SERVICE."
      else
        as_user "mv $MCPATH/minecraft_server.jar.update $MCPATH/$SERVICE"
        echo "Minecraft successfully updated."
      fi
    else
      echo "Minecraft update could not be downloaded."
    fi
  fi
}

mc_backup() {
   mc_saveoff

   NOW=`date "+%Y-%m-%d_%Hh%M"`
   BACKUP_FILE="$BACKUPPATH/${WORLD}_${NOW}.tar"
   echo "Backing up minecraft world..."
   #as_user "cd $MCPATH && cp -r $WORLD $BACKUPPATH/${WORLD}_`date "+%Y.%m.%d_%H.%M"`"
   as_user "tar -C \"$MCPATH\" -cf \"$BACKUP_FILE\" $WORLD"

   echo "Backing up $SERVICE"
   as_user "tar -C \"$MCPATH\" -rf \"$BACKUP_FILE\" $SERVICE"
   #as_user "cp \"$MCPATH/$SERVICE\" \"$BACKUPPATH/minecraft_server_${NOW}.jar\""

   mc_saveon

   echo "Compressing backup..."
   as_user "gzip -f \"$BACKUP_FILE\""
   echo "Done."
}

mc_command() {
  command="$1";
  if pgrep -u $USERNAME -f $SERVICE > /dev/null
  then
    pre_log_len=`wc -l "$MCPATH/$MCLOG" | awk '{print $1}'`
    echo "$SERVICE is running... executing command"
    as_user "screen -p 0 -S minecraft -X eval 'stuff \"$command\"\015'"
    sleep 1 # assumes that the command will run and print to the log file in less than .1 seconds
    # print output
    tail -n $[`wc -l "$MCPATH/$MCLOG" | awk '{print $1}'`-$pre_log_len] "$MCPATH/$MCLOG"
  fi
}

mc_log() {
  cat $MCPATH/$MCLOG
}


#Start-Stop here
case "$1" in
  start)
    mc_start
    ;;
  stop)
    mc_stop
    ;;
  restart)
    mc_stop
    mc_start
    ;;
  update)
    mc_stop
    mc_backup
    mc_update
    mc_start
    ;;
  backup)
    mc_backup
    ;;
  status)
    if pgrep -u $USERNAME -f $SERVICE > /dev/null
    then
      echo "$SERVICE is running."
    else
      echo "$SERVICE is not running."
    fi
    ;;
  command)
    if [ $# -gt 1 ]; then
      shift
      mc_command "$*"
    else
      echo "Must specify server command (try 'help'?)"
    fi
    ;;
  log)
    mc_log
    ;;

  *)
  echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|update|backup|status|restart|log|command \"server command\"}"
  exit 1
  ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Once this script is placed in /etc/init.d it will start the minecraft server automatically when the system is ready, and shut the server down when the system goes down. You can interact with the server by running

```
service minecraft {start|stop|update|backup|status|restart|log|command "server command"}
```

Please do note, however, that you will probably need to configure the minecraft server to hold a limited world and turn down the visibility range slightly to allow the pi to keep up.

Answer (score 1):

@goldilocks solved it! 
I'll explain it, because the script I used was for starting the server in the same directory it did not work(The script and the server where in the same directory). But as he explained said, placing  `cd /path/to/minecraft/directory`  on top of the script solved the problem. I just put the path to the script in the rc.local and it runs now! What @bex said is also a good option! I'll use that one on my other Pi! Thank you!